# What does it mean that a probability distribution has full support?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am reading an article which introduces the following assumption at a certain point:

*The probability distribution of the* (real- valued) *random variable $X$ has full support and is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.*

I am confused on what is commonly intended by "full support". Does the author want to say that the support is $\mathbb{R}$? (which, together with absolute continuity, would then imply that the cumulative distribution function is strictly positive - and, hence, strictly monotone increasing - on $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: The support of a function is the part of the domain which takes nonzero values.  E.g. the support of $x^2$ is $(-\infty,0) \cup (0, \infty)$.  I suppose full support means the support is the same as the domain, as you say.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Dzoooks

Comment: Sorry, I am not too familiar with the topic but why do we need the absolute continuity to imply the strict positivity?